# Can halt() stop the animation at the end state?

Tags: famo.us

I want halt() my translate animation and have it instantly end up at its final location.  halt() currently stops the animation where it currently is.

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
var Easing = require('famous/transitions/Easing');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var surface = new Surface({
  size: [100, 100],
  content: 'click me to halt',
  properties: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FA5C4F'
  }
});

var stateModifier = new StateModifier({
  origin: [0.5, 0]
});

mainContext.add(stateModifier).add(surface);

stateModifier.setTransform(
  Transform.translate(0, 300, 0),
  { duration : 8000, curve: 'linear' }
);

surface.on('click', function() {
  stateModifier.halt();
  surface.setContent('halted');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does seem very hacky.. why don't you just apply the same transform without a transition..

```
surface.on('click', function() {
    stateModifier.halt();
    stateModifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0, 300, 0));
    surface.setContent('halted');
});
```

EDIT:

Even better you can just get the final transform directly..

```
surface.on('click', function() {
  stateModifier.setTransform(stateModifier.getFinalTransform());
  surface.setContent('halted');
});
```

Comment: You're right.  I thought I had tried something like this but perhaps not in the exact way that you outlined.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a hack for this, at least for pre-0.2.0.

You can set the final state using Translate.set() using a very large number to force the last state of the animation.

It would be nice to see support for this somehow with halt() in future versions of Famo.us

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
var Easing = require('famous/transitions/Easing');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var surface = new Surface({
  size: [100, 100],
  content: 'click me to halt',
  properties: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FA5C4F'
  }
});

var stateModifier = new StateModifier({
  origin: [0.5, 0]
});

mainContext.add(stateModifier).add(surface);

stateModifier.setTransform(
  Transform.translate(0, 300, 0),
  { duration : 8000, curve: 'linear' }
);

surface.on('click', function() {
  // This forces the translate animation to its end state
  var translate = stateModifier._transformState.translate;
  translate.set(translate.get(Number.MAX_VALUE));
  surface.setContent('halted');
});
```